# SQL, get rows from different tables in one sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to get two different values from table. I want to get, distinct count of duplicates and want to get total count.

```
WITH contrato_group AS 
(
    SELECT CONTRATO as u_contract, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM `table` 
    GROUP BY CONTRATO
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT u_contract) AS at_least_one_count 
FROM
    contrato_group
WHERE 
    count > 1
```

This is ok, it returns at least one contract counts. But I want to select total count from original table too.

```
SELECT COUNT(CONTRATO) as total_contract 
FROM `table`
```

I tried, union all them.

```
WITH contrato_group AS
(
    SELECT CONTRATO AS u_contract, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM `table` 
    GROUP BY CONTRATO
) 
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT u_contract) AS at_least_one_count 
FROM
    contrato_group
WHERE 
    count > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    COUNT(CONTRATO) AS total_contracts 
FROM
    `table`
```

It returned what I want, but the values were only in a one column. like this:

```
Row     at_least_one_count   
--------------------------
  1     83084    
  2     22894
```

I want to get result like this:

```
Row   at_least_one_count    total_count
----------------------------------------
 1         22894                83084
```

Comment: If you are sure that you only have 1 row on each result set, you can do a `CROSS JOIN` between them.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a subselect

```
with contrato_group as (SELECT CONTRATO as u_contract, count(*) as count
FROM `table` 
GROUP BY CONTRATO) 

SELECT count(distinct u_contract) as at_least_one_count,
(SELECT count(CONTRATO) from `table`) as total_count
from contrato_group
WHERE count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in single statement via *window* function if your *DBMS* has support :

```
select t.*
from (select distinct contrato as u_contract, 
             count(*) over (partition by contrato) as at_least_one_count,  
             count(*) over () as total_count
      from table 
     ) t
where at_least_one_count  > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
with   contrato_group as (SELECT CONTRATO as u_contract, count(*) as count
       FROM test_table
       GROUP BY CONTRATO)
SELECT count(case when count > 1 then 1 end) as duplicate_count, 
       sum(count) as total_count
from   contrato_group;
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle for you to play around with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44597/2)